# Maximum modulus of a complex rational function $r(z)$ on a unit circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

If $r(z) =\frac{p(z)}{\prod_{j=1}^n(z-z_j)}$ where all coefficients of the polynomial $p(z)$ are non negative and real and all $z_j$ are real and $z_j> 1$ for all $j$. Then why is the maximum modulus of $r(z)$ on the unit circle obtained at $z=1$?

Comment: It's not true: take for example $p(z)=1$ and $n=1$ and $z_j$ very close to $-1$. Do you mean that the $z_j$ are all real and nonnegative? Can $z_j=1$?

Comment: Z_j> 1 for all j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator achieves its maximum at $1$ since its coefficients are non-negative. In fact, for any $z$ on the circle, by the triangle inequality, if $p(z)=a_nz^n+...+a_0,$
$$|p(z)|\le |a_n||z|^n+...+|a_0|=a_n+...+a_0=p(1).$$

The norm of the denominator is the product of $|z-z_j|$, which achieves minimum at $1$ (shortest distance). Thus the norm of the whole function achieves its maximum at $1.$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @InspireMaths   You are welcome. If this answer helps you, you could accept it as a correct answer to close this thread.